# RegExp for anything that is not a - or any word character

Tags: javascript, regex

What would the javascript RegExp be for anything that is not a `-` or any word character? I tried `[^-\w]`, but I got a console error. Any ideas?

Comment: WHAT ERROR? When you go see your doctor do you tell him you're sick, period?

Comment: if I use this in .replace() will it replace everything but words numbers and dashes in a string?

Comment: No, you have to specify the global flag for that: `result = old.replace(/[^\w\-]/g, "")`. (replaces anything but - and word characters by nothing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you put it in forward slashes?

```
var rex = /[^\w-]/;
```

works for me in all browsers tested. (Note: I put the - at the end as a matter of good practice, so it never gets confused with a range token.)

Comment: For some reason I forgot that. It does not show any errors now it just doesn't do what I want it to do. Must be a bug in another part of the code then.

Comment: What function are you using in what context? `String.replace()`, `String.match`, `RegExp.test`, ... on string ...?

Answer (score 1):

`-` is a special character inside character classes, indicating character ranges. It should be escaped to be interpreted als a literal '-'. So, for not matching words and `-`, use:

```
/[^\w\-]/
```

Comment: Except the OP wants to NOT match the result.

Comment: `\w` is absolutely fine inside a character class.  It's often used this way to shorten regexes.  e.g. `[a-zA-Z_0-9]` can be rewritten as `[\w\d]`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I rewrote the answer completely to match the question.

Comment: Also, the `-` doesn't need to be escaped if it is the first or last character in the class.

Comment: Actually the regex works as in the OP. No need to escape `-` if it's the first or last character in the class. It's still a good idea to escape it, but not necessary.

Comment: It's better to escape it to avoid future errors. If you'ld like to accept undercores too, you might put it in the character class without checking the previous values. As a result, the code is not working as expected.

Comment: @gnarf: more specifically, it doesn't need to be escaped if it doesn't form part of a range. `[A-Z-\t]`, for instance, is perfectly valid.  It's just good practice to put it at the start or the end.

Answer (score 0):

try the following in your favorite js console

```
/[-\w]/.test('-')
/[-\w]/.test('word')
/[-\w]/.test('-w')
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have the correct regular expression - just remember to enclose in slashes: /[^-\w]/:

```
"-".match(/[^-\w]/)
null
"a".match(/[^-\w]/)
null
"0".match(/[^-\w]/)
null
" ".match(/[^-\w]/)
[" "]
```